# Device file under /dev generated on ubuntu, but not on vanilla linux for a character device driver

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I'm doing a test with a simple character device driver. Today I found a strange case.
When this driver is insmod'ed on ubunutu 20.04, the /dev/axpu_device file is generated. But when the same driver is insmod'ed on vanilla linux (5.4.21), the /dev/axpu_device file is not generated.  Below is the driver initialization code.

```
static int __init chr_driver_init(void)
{
    /* Allocating Major number */
    if ((alloc_chrdev_region(&dev, 0, 1, "axpu_Dev")) < 0) {
        printk(KERN_INFO"Cannot allocate the major number..\n");
        return -1;
    }

    printk(KERN_INFO"Major = %d Minor = %d..\n",MAJOR(dev),MINOR(dev));
    
    /* creating cdev structure */
    cdev_init(&axpu_cdev, &fops);
    axpu_cdev.owner = THIS_MODULE;

    /* Adding character device to the system */
    if ((cdev_add(&axpu_cdev,dev,1)) < 0) {
        printk(KERN_INFO "Cannot add the device to the system...\n");
        goto r_class;
    }

    /* creating struct class */
    if ((dev_class = class_create(THIS_MODULE, "axpu_class")) == NULL) {
        printk(KERN_INFO "cannot create the struct class...\n");
        goto r_class;
    }

    if ((device_create(dev_class, NULL, dev, NULL, "axpu_device")) == NULL) {
        printk(KERN_INFO "cannot create the device ..\n");
        goto r_device;
    }
    else { printk(KERN_INFO "axpu_device created..\n"); }

    vaddr = ioremap(AXPU_BASE, 0x80000);    
    if(!vaddr)
    {
        printk(KERN_INFO"Failed to map the address.\n");
        release_mem_region(AXPU_BASE,AXPU_SIZE);
        return 1;
    }
    printk("----- AXPU_BASE mapped at vaddr = %px\n", vaddr);

    printk(KERN_INFO "Device driver inserted ..done properly..\n");
    return 0;

r_device :
    class_destroy(dev_class);

r_class :
    unregister_chrdev_region(dev,1);
    return -1;
}
```

In vanilla linux too, the class_create and device_create functions doesn't return NULL and when I look at /sys/dev/char, there is the 236:0 directory which is the assigned device number.
I have no idea why there is a difference. (between ubuntu 20.04 and vanilla linux 5.4.21).
Can anybody give me a suggestion where to look?

Comment: Just create the file, no? `mknod /dev/... c 236 0`. On ubuntu most probably udev creates the file.

Comment: @KamilCuk yeap that works. (thanks!) BTW, if I use mkdev (before the driver is loaded), should I remove only the device_create function maybe?.. at least I can proceed to next problem.  But still want to know what makes the difference.

Comment: Why would you remove the device_create function?  That's what creates the struct device in the kernel.  mknod is just to create a directory entry in /dev.  Also why are you not saving the returned dev?  How will you use or free it?